# installing a module in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to  get ngx-date-picker running in my angular 2 app.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-date-picker

The install instructions seem pretty sparse and the demo is non-existent, so I'm poking through it at a snail's pace.

We are using **yarn**, so I ran **yarn add ngx-date-picker --save** on the folder below node_modules, and now I have a /ngx-date-picker/ folder in there.

I've gone in to **package.json** and have added the component, but I don't really know if I've got the syntax right:

```
{
  "name": "arv2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build-prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack",
    "watch-build": "webpack --progress --colors --watch",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n --i18nFormat=xlf",
    "publish-prod": "yarn run build-prod && yarn run publish",
    "publish": "dotnet publish -o \"..\\Publish\\leaves\"",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "prepree2e": "npm start",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "ngx-date-picker": "^0.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.7.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

Now I've got into **app.module.ts** and done the import, like it says in the readme:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { LocalizationLoader } from './modules/localization-loader/localization-loader';

import { serviceConfigFactory, AppConfig } from './app.config';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from "./components/about/about.component";
import { LoginComponent } from './components/account/login/login.component';
import { AuthModule } from './modules/auth/auth.module';
import { ArV2Service } from './services/arv2.service';
import { CompanyModule } from './modules/company/company.module';
import { CompanyComponent } from './components/account/company/company.component';
import { SiteService } from './services/site.service';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ngx-date-picker';
```

and then

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AboutComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        CompanyComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        DatepickerModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        AuthModule,
        CompanyModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({...})
        ...
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio tells me it **cannot find module 'ngx-date-picker'**.

It also can't find 
**'./ngx-date-picker'** or **'ngx-date-picker/ngx-date-picker'** or **'ngx-date-picker/ngx-date-picker.js'** or any other combination.

Not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

In web site detail installation is given but please check given below steps:

```
1.step:  yarn add ngx-date-picker --save-dev
```

then check that installed bootstrap because this module needs bootstrap 3 or 4.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<!--- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

if you use bootstrap 4 and normal CSS, please check the styles file as

```
"styles": [  
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",  
   "styles.css"  
   ],
```

I think it will be enough to use by importing

```
 import {DatepickerModule} from 'ngx-date-picker';
```

Comment: Except for step 1, none of those should stop the app from finding ngx-date-picker. Yes, I have bootstrap 3.3.7 installed. Still cannot find ngx-date-picker.

Comment: What about adding it to the packages.json? "ngx-date-picker": "^0.0.0",

Comment: OK. My fault. The way our projects are structured, we have multiple projects in nearly identical folders. I was in the wrong one.

Comment: Perhaps deleting this question is appropriate then.